# ThickBox - update inside without redirect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, thickbox

ASP.NET MVC and jQuery ThickBox.
I show some content in ThickBox. It includes file upload form

The view multi-media.apsx

```
<form action="/upload/multi-media" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">File name:</label><br />
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" /> 
</form>
<% if (Model.Count > 0) { %>
  <% foreach (FileInfo mediaFile in Model) { %>
    <img width="100px" height="100px" 
      src="<%:ResolveUrl("~/audio.png") %>" border="0" alt="<%: mediaFile.Name %>" />                //................
```

After file upload I redirect to **/upload/multi-media** action and content shows **in normal window, not in ThickBox.**

```
[ActionName("multi-media"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult MultiMedia(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{          
    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        file.SaveAs(GenerateNewFileName(fullFileName));
        return View("multi-media", model);
    }
}
```

How can I stay into ThickBox after file upload? I need show content in ThickBox all the time, even after the file upload.

**UPDATE:** The ajax file upload. Anyway reload ThickBox. Why?

The view **multi-media.apsx**

> ```
>      <div id="mydiv">
>         <% Html.RenderPartial("MultiMediaDetails", Model); %> </div>
> ```

**MultiMediaDetails.ascx**

> ```
>     <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<List<FileInfo>>"%>
>     <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
>  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("multi-media", "upload" ,
>     new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "mydiv", HttpMethod = "Post"   }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
> { %>
>
>   <label for="file">File name:</label><br />
>   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />&nbsp;
>   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
>
>  <% }%>
>
>  <% if (Model.Count > 0)
>    {
>      foreach (FileInfo mediaFile in Model)
>       {
>           //...................  .............."/>
> ```

Comment: Indent code with 4 spaces.  `<` is supported.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do an HTML file upload through Ajax, so the only way to avoid a page reload is to place the uploader in an `iframe` or use a Flash uploader like SWFUpload.

Comment: Why I cannot do an HTML file upload through Ajax? I know I cannot, but why? I cannot use iframe, because ThickBox returns some values to the parent window.

Comment: I'm not sure why JavaScript/HTML was designed that way.  It really wasn't designed for Ajax to begin with.

Comment: If it's an option for your target audience, I'd recommend using a Flash uploader anyway.  HTML file uploading is extremely bad (can't be styled very easily, only uploads one file at a time, requires a post-back, cannot control the file types shown in the file browser, has no progress callbacks, etc.).  You'll save yourself from potential loads of grief by using a Flash uploader (SWFUpload is great).

Comment: I have used iframe. I works good. BUT. After file upload I need to refresh ThickBox content(files list, see my code )to show uploaded new file. How I can do it WITHJOUT redirect to another page or destroy ThickBox?

Comment: I don't want use a Flash, because I will need learn action script language. I prefer use silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight would work too.  If you use SWFUpload, you don't have to learn ActionScript; they provide a SWF with a JavaScript interface.

Comment: Regarding the iframe, I'd suggest that in the iframe page, you emit JavaScript after the file upload.  The JavaScript would communicate with the host page so that you could have your ThickBox update its content.